# Layout se adaptar ao redimensionamento do navegador

Tags: google-chrome, layout-responsivo, internet-explorer, firefox, redimensionamento

Observando muitos sites de hoje em dia, no caso, exclusivamente os com **Layouts** **Responsivos**, reparei num detalhe que não era de minha preocupação até então.

Minha dúvida tem sido em qualificar se uma especificação é imprescindivelmente obrigatória na demanda da construção do layout. Percebi que alguns sites adaptam o conteúdo responsivamente de acordo com a resolução do dispositivo, porem alguns não se adaptam ao **redimensionamento** do navegador (pelo menos não como o esperado).

Isso acontece exclusivamente (pelo menos no que reparei até agora) no Google Chrome, forçando muitas vezes a usar o "*Inspecionar Elemento*"(Mais precisamente o Ctrl+Shift+M).

O fato de não se adaptar ao redimensionar desta forma é uma prática ruim ou é um detalhe sórdido que o "mercado" ignora assim como o costuma ignorar o IE7?

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem.. mas ao fazer um *layout responsive* utiliza-se em grande parte css, com media querys, e desta forma é possível ver as alterações em real-time ao por a "janela" mais pequena, desta forma não simula um telemóvel, mas sim um ecrã mais pequeno..
Este pode ser um dos problemas que esta a relatar. Outro que vejo, é a utilização de java script para detectar se é mobile ou não, ai ao redimensionar a janela as alterações não são visíveis...

Para ter uma melhor simulação, tirando a parte mais obvia que é testar num dispositivo movel.. sugiro que utilize a ferramenta do chrome "device mode"
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/

Espero ter ajudado um pouco ;)
Abraço